# Using a Backbone Collection without a data source (no url)

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

First time posting here... looking forward to see how it all works, but have really appreciated reading other's questions & answers.

I am using backbone for a small app and have found it helpful to use a collection to store some information that is only required during the current session. (I have a number of collections and all the others connect to my API to store/retrieve data).

I read here ([in backbone.js can a Model be without any url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887994/in-backbone-js-can-a-model-be-without-any-url)) that it is possible, and even good to use a collection without providing a url.

Now I would like to add a row of data to the collection... simple:

```
myCollection.create(data);
```

but of course that now throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

Is there any way to use a Backbone collection, be able to add new rows of data (models) to it, but not sync to any sort of data source. Or can you suggest another solution.

I guess I could just use an object to hold the data, but I was enjoying the consistency and functionality.

I am using Backbone.Marionette if that has any impact.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One thing you could do is override the `Backbone.Model` methods that communicate with the server, i.e. `sync`, `fetch`, and `save`... for example:

```
var App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {}
};

App.Models.NoUrlModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
App.Models.NoUrlModel.prototype.sync = function() { return null; };
App.Models.NoUrlModel.prototype.fetch = function() { return null; };
App.Models.NoUrlModel.prototype.save = function() { return null; };

App.Collections.NoUrlModels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.NoUrlModel,
    initialize: function(){}
});

var noUrlModels = new App.Collections.NoUrlModels();
noUrlModels.create({'foo': 'bar'});  // no error
// noUrlModels.models[0].attributes == {'foo': 'bar'};
```

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vdt3g/1/)

Comment: Very clear concise explanation. Thank you. I hadn't realised it was so easy to override methods like this!

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that you can also specify the `sync`, `fetch` and `save` methods in your model definition without referring to the prototype chain.